# Finding installation directory of a program on windows from python

Tags: python, windows, path

A python program needs to find the installation location of openoffice.org, which is installed on a Windows XP computer. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You could have a look in the registry using something like win32api.RegConnectRegistry and win32api.RegOpenKeyEx. (I don't have access to a Windows PC to check at the moment...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `_winreg` module on windows: First find out the path in the registry (eg starting `regedit.exe` and using its find function). Then you can query this path as I did it once to find the home directory of R:

```
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\R-core\\R")
value =  _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "InstallPath")[0]
```

**ADDED**:

If you are not familiar with the windows regstry: have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry